# How to convert nhibernate List to IList<T> in C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a list of my model object from NHibernate result set and would wish to have a generic method to convert it to
IList

I have this

```
var l = session.CreateSQLQuery(@query).SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap).List();
```

need to convert to

```
IList<T> ls = new List<T>();
```

such that any List returned from nhibernate can easily be matched to any model class

I have tried

```
List<T> newList = l.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

but am getting error

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' to type SalesModel
```

where SalesModel is T my generic model

and also have tried

```
var l = session
    .CreateSQLQuery(@query)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<SalesModel>())
    .List();

IList<SalesModel> newList = l.Cast<SalesModel>().ToList();
```

and getting this error

```
A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.PropertyAccessException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
NHibernate.PropertyAccessException: The type System.Decimal can not be assigned to a property of type System.Int32 setter of model.SalesModel.total ---> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.
```

And this is my model class

```
  public class SalesModel
    {
        public virtual String barcode { get; set; }
        public virtual String product_name { get; set; }
        public virtual int total { get; set; }
   
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to change the `int` to a `decimal` so the model type matches the database type. But really this is a slightly different question than you originally asked. @rytisk gave a great answer to the original question. This one sounds like it should be asked as a new question.

Comment: @RufusL have tried rytisk that where am getting that error this is the one post had posted earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775593/nhibernate-generic-method-to-query-different-model

Comment: Right, but this error has nothing to do with the original question or his answer. This is now about mapping the types from your database to the model.

Comment: @RufusL How can my model class to make it generic such that i can pass different model class as per this earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775593/nhibernate-generic-method-to-query-different-model

Comment: `IList<T> result = session.CreateSQLQuery(@query).SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<T>()).List<T>();` Of course the `@query` has to return a type that can be converted to `T`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the returned collection `l` contains items of type `System.Collections.Hashtable`. This is because you used `Transformers.AliasToEntityMap` which says:

> Each row of results is a map (System.Collections.IDictionary) from alias to values/entities.

To make items of type `SalesModel` you need to use `Transformers.AliasToBean<SalesModel>()` which:

> Creates a result transformer that will inject aliased values into instances of T via property methods or fields.

And then you could cast it or use `List<T>()` instead:

```
IList<SalesModel> list = session
    .CreateSQLQuery(@query)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<SalesModel>())
    .List<SalesModel>();
```

Comment: now am gettting error A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.PropertyAccessException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
NHibernate.PropertyAccessException: The type System.Decimal can not be assigned to a property of type System.Int32 setter of SalesModel.total ---> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.

Comment: As you can see from the error it has something to do with the Properties of your `SalesModel` class. In particular, `SalesModel.Total` property is expected to be of type `decimal` but is an `int`. Means your `SalesModel` class doesn't match your database table.

Comment: @RufusL my main objective is to create a generic method that accepts any model. If I remove cast am still getting the error. It forces me to AddScalar method that will my method not generic

Comment: @rytisk my main objective is to create a generic method that accepts any model. If I remove cast am still getting the error. It forces me to AddScalar method that will my method not generic

Comment: @MorganDev The `NHibernate.PropertyAccessException` you are getting is because your class doesn't match the database table. Change `public virtual int total { get; set; }` to `public virtual decimal total { get; set; }` on your SalesModel and try again.

Comment: @rytisk thanks alot that was the cause of the error and upvoted your answer